# How to return a NodeSeq without a root node?

Tags: xml, scala, parsing

I'm new to Scala and I'm working in a project written fully in Scala, and I want to modify a case class that contains a method that return a NodeSeq, but all the class parameters are Optional and I should return just the available parameters parsed as a NodeSeq.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the method it's just returning the first element in the sequence:

```
case class Address(
                        street: Option[String],
                        number: Option[String],
                        complement: Option[String],
                        district: Option[String],
                        city: Option[String],
                        state: Option[String],
                        country: Option[String],
                        postalCode: Option[String]
                      ) {
  def toXml: NodeSeq =
    {street.map(x => <street>{x}</street>).orNull}
    {number.map(x => <number>{x}</number>).orNull}
    {complement.map(x => <complement>{x}</complement>).orNull}
    {district.map(x => <district>{x}</district>).orNull}
    {city.map(x => <city>{x}</city>).orNull}
    {state.map(x => <state>{x}</state>).orNull}
    {country.map(x => <country>{x}</country>).orNull}
    {postalCode.map(x => <postalCode>{x}</postalCode>).orNull}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting parsed as

```
def toXml: NodeSeq = {
  street.map(x => <street>{x}</street>).orNull
}

{number.map(x => <number>{x}</number>).orNull}
{complement.map(x => <complement>{x}</complement>).orNull}
/* etc */
```

The first line is the body of `toXml` function, and everything after that goes to the body of the class and thus is part of the class constructor.

In your case the easiest way is probably to take an empty `NodeSeq` and to add every `Option[Node]` to it.

```
def toXml: NodeSeq = NodeSeq.Empty ++
  street.map(x => <street>{x}</street>) ++
  number.map(x => <number>{x}</number>) ++
  complement.map(x => <complement>{x}</complement>) ++
  district.map(x => <district>{x}</district>) ++
  city.map(x => <city>{x}</city>) ++
  state.map(x => <state>{x}</state>) ++
  country.map(x => <country>{x}</country>) ++
  postalCode.map(x => <postalCode>{x}</postalCode>)
```